# Ant, concat: Not able to add a carriage return line feed

Tags: ant, concatenation

I am running ant 1.9.4 on Windows. eol option doesn't seem to work correctly.
I have tried:

```
<concat destfile="${result.file}" append="true" fixlastline="yes" eol="crlf">SUCCESS</concat>
```

and

```
<concat destfile="${result.file}" append="true" fixlastline="true" eol="crlf">SUCCESS</concat>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
Tony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) says the following about the `fixlastline` attribute:

> This attribute does not apply to embedded text.

You can instead use the `line.separator` property:

```
<concat destfile="out.txt" append="true">SUCCESS${line.separator}</concat>
```